# ionic3 bootstrap and tag loading fail with android

Tags: css, ionic-framework

In my app when I ionic serve or run android(for android device view) , the css of app I guess doesn't load well css bootstrap and ion-segment fails, when I refresh the page it returns normally.How could it be done or where do you think that I'm wrong.

Note:With running ionic lab (IOS) it runs normally like the right picture.but android needs refresh(not even talkig about windows platform view its much worse then android :D )

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out that it is not an error.I checked ionicframework web page and saw that segment is showed at android like that.And whenever I refresh the page it returns ios view.

Thank you for all